# React Native - Returning Undefined when List is not

Tags: react-native

We're having some trouble with an Android App we are developing.

Essentially we're trying to get a word from an input box, use that word to get a list of synonyms (from an API), and then save that list.

Here is one section of our code where we're using the API to get a list of synonyms - notice the returning of list at the end:

```js
export async function getString(concept, whatlist) {
  fetch(`...link - uses concept...`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseJson => {
      var list = [];
      if (whatlist == 'words') {
        list = responseJson.response[0].items.map((val, key) => {
          return val.item;
        });
      } else if (whatlist == 'weights') {
        list = responseJson.response[0].items.map((val, key) => {
          return val.weight;
        });
      }
      return list;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

However, when we try to call this in another file, the returned thing comes out as undefined. We used console.warn and verified that we're getting the right things from the API, and that the list wasn't undefined, but somehow when it's in the other file "res" becomes undefined.

```js
storeData = async () => {
  var nameobjectlist = [];

  var singularConcept = this.state.input1.split('\n')[0];
  var i;

let stringList = [];
let weightList = [];

arrayMaker
  .getString(singularConcept, 'words')
  .then(res => {
    console.warn('Striasdfsdzfx' + res);
    stringList = res;
    arrayMaker
      .getString(singularConcept, 'weights')
      .then(res => {
        weightList = res;
      })
      .then(res2 => {
        for (var ii = 0; ii < stringList.length; ii++) {
          nameobjectlist.push(weightedwords(stringList[ii], weightList[ii]));
        }
        var specificwordlist = this.state.input2.split('\n')[0];
        nameobjectlist.push(weightedwords(specificwordlist[i], 100));

        AsyncStorage.setItem('@AllObjects', nameobjectlist);

        this.props.navigation.navigate('SamplePages');
      });
  })
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
};
```

Are we missing anything here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. you are not returning anything from the getString function that's why you are getting undefined.
2. There is no need to make the getString method async because fetch method returns a promise.

The below modification should solve your issue.

```js
export function getString (concept, whatlist){
 return fetch(...link - uses concept...)
    .then( (response) => response.json() )
    .then( (responseJson) => {
     // rest of your code
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

fetch will return a promise. You have to resolve the promise before you return.

```
 export async function getString (concept, whatlist){
 fetch(...link - uses concept...)
    .then( (response) => response.json() )
    .then( (responseJson) => {
      var list = [];
      if (whatlist == "words") {
        list = responseJson.response[0].items.map((val, key) => {
          return val.item
        });
      }
      else if (whatlist == "weights") {
        list = responseJson.response[0].items.map((val, key) => {
          return val.weight
        });
      }
      resolve(list);
    }
    )
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
      resolve([]);
    });
}
```

or you can use async await for making an API call to avoid promises.